# What is your opinion on the Falcon language?

Tags: programming-languages, falcon

[Falcon](http://www.falconpl.org/) is a programming language that supports multiple paradigms like message passing, OO, functional, and yet the code looks nice and clean.

What do you think, does it have a chance to take off and be used as a general purpose programming glue language? Is it worth exploring? What are your impressions so far if you used it in real projects?

Comment: It first appeared in 2002-2003 so I don't know about a new language.

Comment: Fair enough, it is new to me :)

Answer (score 7):

I've downloaded it. It's powerful, flexible, Unicode-aware, and in use in real-world situations, namely as the scripting language for [AuroraUX](http://www.auroraux.net/index.php/Main_Page).

> Falcon is our scripting language of choice. "Simple, fast and powerful programming language, easy to learn and to feel comfortable with, and a scripting engine ready to empower mission-critical multithreaded applications." -- http://www.auroraux.org/index.php/AuroraUX:About

Speaking of Unicode, this is a real Falcon script:

```
// International class; name and street
class 国際( なまえ, Straße )
   // set class name and street address
   नाम = なまえ
   شَارِع   =  Straße
   // Say who am I!
   function 言え!()
     >@"I am $(self.नाम) from ",self.شَارِع
   end
end
// all the people of the world! 
民族 = [ 国際( "高田　Friederich", "台湾" ),
   国際( "Smith Σωκράτης", "Cantù" ),
   国際( "Stanisław Lec", "południow" ) ]

for garçon in 民族: garçon.言え!()
```

Comment: Wow. This is what "polyglot programming" term should be used for.

Comment: Unicode identifiers may seem spectacular, but I believe this is supported by many popular programming languages including java, C#, C++ (though your C++ compiler needs to support it) and python (since version 3).

Answer (score 7):

It currently has a small but active developer community and so it's currently at the state where the cool features are really solidifying. Given that the interpreter is currently almost completely unoptimised, it still runs at a very impressive speed.

I know of someone using for all the scripting in their game (replacing Lua) and as far as I know, they've found it a pleasure to use.

Answer (score 5):

While it looks interesting, and has some cool ideas, I don't see much use in learning it unless it's used in industry and or academia.

The history of programming languages is littered with great languages that have fallen to the way side because no one adopted them.

Their features are however often incorporated into more popular languages.

That said Ruby was created in 1993 and rarely heard of it till it got used in Ruby on Rails. Now it's the next big new shiny thing.

So maybe in 2023 I'll be eating my words, but then again if Falcon is a good language and I need to use it then it should be easy enough to pick it up.

Comment: And how do it get to be used in industry and academia unless industrialists and academicians adopt it?

Comment: I found this answer totally vapid, adds nothing new that anybody does not know.

Comment: I'm touched that you took the time to comment. The question did ask for an opinion I gave mine.

Comment: Almost 2023 and Ruby is almost as forgotten by the masses again like Smalltalk, Lisp, and Perl was already in 2009.
 
But whats the shiny new scripting language now? Looks like nothing came up in the last 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

*What do you think, does it have a chance to take off and be used as a general purpose programming glue language?*  no one knows!
*Is it worth exploring?* I guess any language is worth to take a look at
*What are your impressions so far if you used it in real projects?* I have not used it
Today a race exists to see who creates the most sofisticated language borrowing syntax among them.
Regarding easy to read programs, we can depart from assembly language (and esoteric languages!), following near english ones (C, Java, PHP and Delphi my favorite) and finally english like ones. For example, COBOL.
¿Do we really need a new language? hard to tell. Java was regarded a curiosity and quickly got strong influence in the industry. Dart on the other hand, promised a lot and still have not heard of nobody using it.
Where will *Falcon* will be positioned? Only time will tell. Personally, I find it's syntax too sofisticated (and also Java, PHP and C). I have been programming in Pascal for many years (and its variants) and prefer something like:
`Writeln('I am ',age,'years old and my zipcode is ',zipcode);`
Than C++:
`cout << "I am " << age << " years old and my zipcode is " << zipcode;`
I guess all programmers have a favorite (or in some cases only one) programming language. That leads to the saying "When the only tool you know is a hammer, all problems look like nails!" (perhaps the same can be said about database engines) How many users create "databases" using worksheets?
So, in conclusion I will explore it to enhace my tool box and have a hammer, screwdriver and even a sextant!